# How can I tell the source of an effective permission

Tags: windows, active-directory, permissions, filesystems

I have a user that has read access to a folder.

But they aren't in any AD groups that should have read access to that folder, the don't have explicit rights on the folder or any of the parents, nor are they an owner of the folder.

However, they still have Traverse/List/Read/Read-Extended permissions.

[image: Advanced Security Settings - Effective Permissions Tab]

Is there a way to tell what's giving them those rights (an AD group, etc.)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Effective permissions does not list the source, because it may come from several sources. You need to look at the permissions tab to see where all of the individual components of the effective permissions are coming from. This unfortunately does not give you help in tracking the groups down, but you just need to look thought the Access control entries in the permissions tab. It has to be in there somewhere.

If you need an explanation on how permission set A + B gets you to effective permissions C, then please post a picture or write-up of the entries for that user in the permissions tab.

Comment: Found it eventually, In my case someone had errantly set Authenticated Users on a parent folder.

I did also found some instances of the owner being the user in question that provided higher privileges than I expected on first inspection.